# Has anyone used Huagati DBML Tools ? I wanted to get some hands on feedback

Tags: linq-to-sql

http://www.huagati.com/dbmltools/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been using the Huagati DBML tools for a project for the past five months or so, and just the "Update Linq-to-SQL Diagram from Database" function is worth the registration price.  I haven't run into any compatibility problems, but that's the only 3rd-party add-in for VS2008 that I'm using, so not sure about how it plays with ReSharper.

It still boggles my mind that Microsoft released the Linq-to-sql designer (for .dbml files) without an "update diagram" feature built into it, but the Huagati plug-in does that, plus some other niceties (you can specify how you want to 'prettify' your column-name/properties, so that all my Tablename_Id columns become TablenameID properties. I did have to add a couple lines to the list of fields marked "auto-generated" (by default, my bit columns that default to 0 or 1 weren't marked as auto-generated, even though they are).  A nitpicky complaint is that you can't type in the box that has the list of auto-gen values (you can't hit 'enter' to create a new line - so you have to copy/paste from notepad).

Other than that very, very minor nitpick though, the DBML tools have saved me a ton of time.  I also like the "compare" feature to see what's out of whack before I go and actually commit to changing my Linq classes (also useful for comparing the dev linq ORM classes to a production database, in case you forget to document changes to the dev DB as you go...)

So anyway - after more than 5 months, I give it a thumbs up.

Kirk

Answer (score 1):

If you've moved to Entity Framework this is clearly a tool you should know about. I've been disappointed by the EF designer's "Update Model From Database..." feature and I'm blown away by the simplicity and power of Huagati's Model Comparer tool. The Model Comparer for EFv4 shows differences between the database, SSDL, and CSDL layers and allows individual differences from one layer to be synchronized with another or left in place. I've just watched [the demo video](http://huagati.blogspot.com/2010/07/introducing-model-comparer-for-entity.html) and I'm highly impressed. I wouldn't be surprised to see this sort of tool included in the next version of Visual Studio. Unfortunately I can't give hands on feedback yet, just a heads-up.

Answer (score 0):

If you send an email to support@huagati.com I can put you in touch with some existing users. (Assuming you want to ask other users about their experiences..?)

Or if you have any specific questions on how to use it, please be more specific.

Also, (in case you haven't visited it), the [support forum](http://forum.huagati.com/forum1-huagati-dbmledmx-tools-support.aspx) is a good place to get hold of other users and to ask specific questions about the tool... You can of course also email any questions you may have to support@huagati.com

http://forum.huagati.com/forum1-huagati-dbmledmx-tools-support.aspx

Comment: Thanks, but the reason I posted the question here was to see the reach of Huagati. I did try it myself and have found it useful but have only used it for a day. I was wondering if it gives and problems when ReSharper is also installed along with it.

Comment: Ok, got it. :)  

As for resharper, I am not aware of any problems/incompatibilities. For a couple of versions there was one issue where it ran into a conflict with PowerCommands (resulting in a load error) but that has been resolved.